# selectively remove rows that share a date, leaving the last one of the day

Tags: sql, date, duplicates

I'm working with a table with the following variables:
Reference number (of the thing associated). time/date stamp. event type (coded as int).

Firstly, I'd like some sql code that applies the logic:
'If multiple events occur on the same day for the same reference number, take out all of them except the last one'

Secondly, I'd like some code that (after doing the above) applies the logic:
'If an event is as the same type as the previous event for that reference number, take it out.'

Can you help me with this?

Comment: This isn't a code writing service.  You need to try and do it yourself and then let us know where you are having problems.   "I'd like some code" is never a good thing to say.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be most helpful.  Also helpful... tag which RDMS you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I have to solve problems like this I use the "better than" principle.

e.g.

```
select reference_number, event_type, created_timestamp
from table_name best
left join table_name better_than on better_than.reference_number = best.reference_number and better_than.created_timestamp > best.created_timestamp
where better_than is null;
```

What such a query does is make sure that there is nothing "better than" what I'm after.  I use this pattern to eliminate all sorts of "duplicate" records that I don't want.  Once you have the select statement you can build deletes and other such using it as the guide.

The above solves the first part you need.  To remove duplicate types do a group by and you should be good to go man.

e.g.

```
select reference_number, event_type, created_timestamp
from table_name best
left join table_name better_than on better_than.reference_number = best.reference_number and better_than.created_timestamp > best.created_timestamp
where better_than is null
group by best.event_type;
```